# Magento 2.4 REST API for get order Details thought order Id issue

Tags: magento2.3

```
<route url="/V2/order/:orderId" method="GET"> <service 
class="Custom\Test\Api\OrderDetailsRepositoryInterface" method="getOrderDetails"/> 
<resources> <resource ref="self" /> </resources> <data> <parameter name="customerId" 
force="true">%customer_id%</parameter> </data> </route>
```

Using this for getorderDetails thought order Id
In my module function using this

```
$orderId = 219;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->get($orderId);
$custLastName = $orders->getCustomerLastname();
print_r($custLastName)
```

**But getting this issue**

```
 "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
"parameters": {
    "fieldName": "orderId",
    "fieldValue": null
},
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Headers: Authorization Bearer + [TOKEN]
- Create a order with get /V2/order/219

How can i solve?? it's a bug or i forgot something? i've seen a lot of thread but no one can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<route url="/V2/order/:orderId" method="GET"> 
    <service class="Custom\Test\Api\OrderDetailsRepositoryInterface" method="getOrderDetails"/> 
    <resources> 
        <resource ref="self" /> 
    </resources> 
    <data> 
        <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter> 
    </data> 
</route>
```

> **etc/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Custom\Test\Api\OrderDetailsRepositoryInterface" type="Custom\Test\Model\OrderDetailsRepository" />
```

> **OrderDetailsRepositoryInterface.php**

```
namespace Custom\Test\Api;

use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;

/**
 * Order repository interface.
 * @api
 * @version : 1.0
 */
interface OrderDetailsRepositoryInterface
{
    
    /**
     *
     * @param int $orderId
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return mixed[]
     */
    public function getOrderDetails($orderId, $customerId);
}
```

> **OrderDetailsRepository.php**

```
namespace Custom\Test\Api;

use Custom\Test\Api\OrderDetailsRepositoryInterfac;

class OrderDetailsRepository implements OrderDetailsRepositoryInterfac
{

    protected $order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    ) {
        $this->_order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getOrderDetails($orderId, $customerId)
    {
        $response = [];
        $order = $this->_order->load($orderId);
        if (is_object($order) && $order->getId() > 0)
            $response['increment_id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
        echo "<PRE>";
        print_r($response);
    }
}
```

1. Headers: Authorization Bearer + [CUSTOMER TOKEN]

url = http://127.0.0.1/rest/V2/order/219